# UIWebView loads page but once loaded the page contents do not respond when trying to touch or scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have the following webview in a wrapper view:

```
webWrapperView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0f, frameHeight + 50.0f, frameWidth - 100.0f, frameHeight - 100.0f)];
webWrapperView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
webWrapperView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5.0f, 5.0f);
webWrapperView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3f;
[self.view addSubview:webWrapperView];

webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0f, 50.0f, webWrapperImageView.frame.size.width - 100.0f, webWrapperImageView.frame.size.height - 100.0f)];
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
webView.delegate = self;
webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
webView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
[webWrapperView addSubview:webView];
```

The view loads pages fine with:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedURLString];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

But once the page loads I cannot click any links or enter into inputs, etc. Any ideas oh thou great populous of StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured this out and wanted to record here for anyone else struggling with this one:

Even though my UIWebView has userInteractionEnabled, the wrapper view that contained it DID NOT! If you want subviews to be able to respond to the user then their superviews must also be enabled (It should be enabled by default, but make sure).

Add this to the superview of your UIWebView:

```
webWrapperView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: By default, `UIView` has `userInteractionEnabled = YES`. You must have been setting this to `NO` yourself somewhere in code that you didn't show us.